# Circular dependencies or right way to build a project

Tags: java, gradle, project

I have a project for a web-app.

1. Most classes of this project must be compiled into .jar file and put to server into `codebase/WEB-INF/lib` dir. These classes are used by server only.
2. But I have some classes which need to be used on the server and the client. These classes must be put directly to codebase/[package.class].
3. All of these classes depend on each other and vice-versa.

End of story. Now I try to move my project from IDE build to [Gradle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle). My project contains two modules which depend on each other. InteljID provide warning for me and compile this fine. But with Gradle it gets stuck. So, can I somehow split these classes in two logical groups, and have an easy way to build the structure described above?

I was trying to make multi-project build, several sourceSets but everywhere I got the same circular dependency errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to refactor your code. One way of doing this is to create a separate project for the server specific code, another project for the client project and a common project for code that needs to be shared. Next, you can let the server project and the client project depend on the common project. However, there should not be any dependencies between the server project and client project themselves.

Typically, you would like to keep the common project as small as possible. Ask yourself if a certain class is necessary in both projects? If not, it should not be part of the common package. Make sure to keep your dependencies between classes, packages and projects unidirectional. This may include quite a lot of refactoring since the code is tangled.

Recommended reading:

- [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by "Uncle Bob" Martin
- [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) by Michael Feathers

Answer (score 1):

Here is some little utility that you might find useful to keep your Java code clean of cyclic dependencies:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcycles/

I made it while working on a growing project where I had trouble keeping track of classes inter-dependencies (to avoid cycles) just on top of my mind (all the cycles-related libraries I could find were either broken or too heavy (with complicated GUIs, or embedded in huge frameworks, etc.)).

It can show classes and packages cyclic dependencies (and the involved classes for packages cycles), and the amount of cycles in which each class or package is involved.

The idea is to use it to hunt down cycles if any, and then to regularly run it to make sure there are still no cycles (or only acceptable ones).

-Jeff